# Apply changes in ~/.gitconfig

Tags: git

When I make changes in my `~/.gitconfig` file I find they are only reflected if I restart my computer.

Is there a command to "refresh" git so that the changes in the `~/.gitconfig` file are reflected without restarting my device?

This problem is on a Mac (OS X 10.9.4), but it would be great if there is an answer that is git specific and will work across all platforms.

Comment: `~/.gitconfig` should be read every time you start git. Are you using the git command line utility or some other app for git usage?

Comment: @mtak I am just using git from the command line

Answer (score 22):

use:

```
git init
```

It will reload ~/.gitconfig

Comment: This ruined my existing repository with multiple worktrees!

Edit- after a couple of minutes of panicking, seems like it creates a `.git` folder in my root, bare clone of my repository and `git worktree` was reading from that. I moved this new `.git` folder to another location and voila, things seem to be back to normal.

Comment: `git init` does quite a bit more than that. If all you need is a config-reload, you might wanna look through https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init before trying `git init` for that.